# What is the difference between "find" and "locate" search methods in Catfish?

Tags: search, find, locate

There seem to be two different methods of searching for files in Catfish

[image]

What is the difference?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[`locate`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/man1/locate.findutils.1.html) is fast but bases its results on a local database that needs to be updated for it to find a recent result. Command `updatedb` is usually run daily by `cron` to update the default database.

[`find`](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/find) is real time so does not depend on a local database. Being real time it is also slower than `locate`.

Catfish uses the actual Linux commands so you can find more information on both commands with `man locate`, `man locatedb` and `man find` if the 2 links do not give enough information.